# Node - Render variable into partial layout ejs-locals

Tags: node.js, ejs, passport-local

I'm use passport and I need to my layout (using [ejs-locals 'partial'](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals)) can render my username variable.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals = 
        {
            what : 'MyProject',
            who : req.user.username 
        }
    next();
});
```

I realize *'req.user.username'* only available if *'isAuthenticated'* returning true. The following code works, but Im sure there is a handy way to this instead of writing variable for every routes.

```
app.get('/dashboard',isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    res.render('template/index', {who:req.user.username});
});
```

Then, here is my layout:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav style="margin-bottom: 0">

        <%- partial('header.ejs') %>
        <%- partial('left.ejs') %>

     </nav>

        <%- body %>
</div>
```

and last my header.ejs

```
<span style='padding-left:18px'>Hi, <%=who%></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<% include header.ejs %>` instead.

That works in ejs, not sure if ejs-locals is the same. In header.ejs you should have access to `who`. Worth trying.